# How to Connect to Azure from Visual Studio Code Terminal

Tags: powershell, azure, visual-studio-code

I have installed the required software and Azure PowerShell cmdlets on local system. I tried to execute a powershell script by connecting to Azure from Visual Studio Code Terminal. Below is the error.

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell 

function PublishToAzure{ 
 Add-AzureAccount
......
......
}
```

Error is..
**Add-AzureAccount : The handle is invalid**

**Visual Studio Code** Settings:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{  
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
}
```

Console of **Windows Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell** Properties
Target is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command "Import-Module MSOnline"
```

System Properties: 64bit Win7 OS

Answer (score 1):

You may connect and manage Azure resources from within VS Code's terminal window by installing Microsoft Azure CLI 2.0. (https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCliWindows).

After CLI 2.0 is successfully installed in your environment, add the CLI 2.0 components to your environment path.

For example, my environment is Windows 10 and VS Code v1.13.0. I successfully ran the CLI 2.0 MSI installer for Windows. In my VS Code terminal session, I add the path to my PowerShell environment via this command:

```
$Env:Path += ';C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin'
```

To work within my Azure subscription(s), first I login via the command

```
az login
```

Follow the prompts to browse to a URL to complete the login to your Azure account and authorize the CLI session. Additional help on CLI 2.0 commands may be found at this link,  https://aka.ms/cli

I know this thread is old and my answer a bit late but I hope this helps someone.

Cheers,
CarnegieJ